# Get Items from SharePoint is raising this error :- "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, api, list-view-threshold

I have this Get All Items where i define the threshold to be 100,00 as follow:-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1687898162992.png]

[image: johnjohn123_1-1687898204890.png]

now on runtime >> i will get this error , any advice how to fix this error?

**The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.**

[image: johnjohn123_2-1687898273352.png]

any advice please?

Comment: The Pagination and 100'000 is Ok. try to remove "Order By" and "Filter Query" and see if it works. It can not sort more then >5000 items but 'Get' should work with pagination..

Comment: @GennadyG thanks .. i can Order by single field such as "DesignTypeOrder asc" but if i define 2 Order By fields i will get the threshold error again. not sure what is going on

Comment: Then think You should store results in some temporary table and then sort them there. Something like "power automate sort results more then 5000" in google might help. p.s.: Also sp admin account should work with 20'000 items. Best regards, Gennady

Answer (score 1):

It seems your query is returning over 5000 items, and the Get Items action is unable to return more than this (regardless of the Power Automate pagination setting). You may need to use the SharePoint API directly, using the "Send HTTP request to SharePoint" action and the "nextLink" property that is returned, to fetch large datasets in pagination. This has been discussed in a Power Automate community thread here:

[SharePoint GetItems TopCount](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/SharePoint-GetItems-TopCount/m-p/839883/highlight/true#M66098)

Comment: so you mean the Get item can not retrieve more than 5000 regardless of the pagination we define ? is this dure to multiple filter we are using or something else?

Comment: It seems it's not able to return more than 5000 items, you'll need to paginate using the "Send HTTP request to SharePoint" action.

Comment: now i removed the Order by fields and the Get Item worked well .. not sure why

Comment: The fields are probably indexed, but can't be sorted because you're returning more than 5000 items.

Comment: yes all the filter and order by fields are index, i can Order by single field such as "DesignTypeOrder asc" but if i define 2 Order By fields i will get the threshold error again.not sure what is going on